# Making div and input text to occupy remaining space does not work

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to make the `input` and its container `div` from the following HTML to take the remaining available width ([fiddle provided](http://jsfiddle.net/sGg7M/2/)):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="information">
        <div id="leftcontainer"><lable>Field name:</lable></div>
        <div id="rightcontainer">
            <div id="action">A</div>
            <div id="textdiv">
                <input type="text" style="width:100%;" value="something"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="additional">Additional info</div>
</div>
```

And the relevant part of the CSS:

```
#container, #information, #additional{
    width:600px;
}

#leftcontainer{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;    
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;    
}

#rightcontainer{
    float:right;
    width:67%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#action{
    float:right;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    text-align:center;
}

#textdiv {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

This does not work properly as the input slides under the `#action` div and takes up the entire 67% of it's parent. I've looked and tried the solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032914/how-to-make-a-div-to-fill-a-remaining-horizontal-space-a-very-simple-but-annoyi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537839/fill-remaining-space-with-left-div) but the result did not improve. How can I make the `input` take up the available width in this situation? (Some pointers on how to "fix" the `label`, although not mandatory, are very much appreciated.)

Comment: I'm confused, maybe its because its early in the morning but.. What are you asking for? The input to sit next to the text and take up the remaining space on that line?

Comment: It's definitely to early. I do apologize for the confusion. What I really need is to have the `#textdiv` and `#action` be side by side and the `#textdiv` to automatically take the remaining width in the `#rightcontainer`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this by replacing your styles

```
#container, #information, #additional {
width: 600px;
float: left;
}

#leftcontainer {
float: left;
width: 21%;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 5%;
}

#textdiv {
width: 89%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Setting the with means that if my `#action` width changes, I need to also change the percentage. I can accomplish the same effect using fixed widths but it's not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes in the fiddle, is this what you wanted http://jsfiddle.net/sGg7M/4/

Made below css changes

```
#leftcontainer{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;   
}

#rightcontainer{
    margin-left: 30%;
}
```

edit: made some minor structural changes and more edit to css also removed the border
http://jsfiddle.net/sGg7M/5/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this does not solve my main problem. I do know that removing the absolute positioning (partially) takes care of the issue, but currently that's not an option.

Comment: Why you need position absolute? Instead of top you can simply use margin-top

Comment: @RickyStam, figured that out in the meanwhile. Still, this does not solve my text box issue.

Comment: Did you try CSS3 rule *{box-sizing: border-box;} it might be what you need